# Not able to click asp link button

Tags: asp.net, linkbutton

I have a linkbutton displaying the path of an uploaded document..The tag structure is like so

```
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblDoc" runat="server" Text="Document:"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDoc" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/Transfer.aspx"></asp:LinkButton>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

I am handling the **onclick** event on the server side:

```
Private Sub lnkDoc_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles lnkDoc.Click
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "onclick", "<script language=javascript>window.open('OpenDocument.aspx?DocumentPath=" & System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(lnkDoc.Text) & "', 'OpenUploadedDoc','left=0px,top=0px,width='+screen.availWidth+',height='+screen.availHeight+',menubar=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=1')</script>")
End Sub
```

But I am not able to click the document path. When I hover over the linkbutton, nothing happens. What could be the issue?

**EDIT**:
When I try to add onclick on the client side, I get the following error.

**Transfer.Private Sub lnkDoc_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)' is not accessible in this context because it is 'Private'.**

Comment: where is the text property of lnkDoc

Comment: I haven't added that.

Comment: remove the private modifier. make it protected. then call the function from linkbutton.

Comment: Using Protected doesn't work either...

Comment: "I am handling the onclick event on the server side" - no, you are **handling** it client-side, or at least you try to do so by setting JS handler.

Comment: @Aishvarya can you try my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ASPX**

```
<tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblDoc" runat="server" Text="Document:"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDoc" CausesValidation="false" runat="server" Text="Test"></asp:LinkButton>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

**Code behind**

```
    Private Sub lnkDoc_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles lnkDoc.Click
         ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "onclick", "<script language=javascript>alert('hi')</script>")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

I think there are some validation on your page so click event is not fire so please set causesvalidation="false" of LinkButton as below code and check again:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDoc" causesvalidation="false" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/Transfer.aspx"></asp:LinkButton
```

Thanks,
Hitesh

Answer (score 2):

I have fixed the issue. The problem was with rendering the linkbutton in HTML(which was inside  a panel). So I placed it in a  outside the Panel.

```
    </asp:Panel>
    <div>
            <asp:Label ID="lblDoc" style="margin-left: 3px" Text="Document: " runat="server"></asp:Label>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDoc" style="margin-left:100px" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/Transfer.aspx"></asp:LinkButton>
        </div>
```

Thanks all for your suggestions..!

Answer (score 0):

try to give onclick event on .aspx page, and check it..

i hope that way it will work

Comment: Hi, it doesn't accept onclick event on client side since I have accessed the event as Private on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the click event to link button.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDoc" runat="server"  onclick="lnkDoc_Click"></asp:linkbutton>
```

Page behind file you have to write

```
 Protected Sub lnkDoc_Click((ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lnkDoc.Click
        // code you want to run
    End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, I get this error if i do this. "Error 117 'Transfer.Private Sub lnkDoc_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)' is not accessible in this context because it is 'Private'"

Comment: I have added the code for page behind file in my answer. Please check it.

Comment: Make the lnkDoc_Click method public

Comment: I have notice that in your link button code you did not set the Text Property of the button . Second you have mention the PostBackUrl which post back the page to another page. Please set Text property and remove the PostBackUrl url property. your link button code should be <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDoc" runat="server"  onclick="lnkDoc_Click" Text="Click Me" ></asp:linkbutton>

Answer (score 0):

```
Protected Sub lnkDoc_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles lnkDoc.Click
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "onclick", "<script language=javascript>window.open('OpenDocument.aspx?DocumentPath=" & System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(lnkDoc.Text) & "', 'OpenUploadedDoc','left=0px,top=0px,width='+screen.availWidth+',height='+screen.availHeight+',menubar=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=1')</script>")
End Sub
```

**Note:** make your event **Protected** not **Private**

And also You need to add the click event to link button.

```
  <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDoc" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/Transfer.aspx" onclick="lnkDoc_Click"></asp:linkbutton>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add text to the button and make the handler public.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to set `LinkButton.OnClientClick` property? It let's you specify client-side handler for rendered link button control. 
Take a look:

```
<asp:linkbutton id="LinkButton1" text="Open Web site" onclientclick="Navigate()" onclick="LinkButton1_Click" runat=Server />
```

Here `Navigate()` is a JavaScript function called upon click, and `LinkButton1_Click` is a server side event handler.

You want to open a new browser window to display a document when user clicks a link, right?
So a better approach will be to create JavaScript function with `documentPath` parameter (set on the server-side). No need to for messy `RegisterStartupScript`. You seem to run in circles now. Take a step back and rethink what you really want your code to do.

Comment: It works, unfortunately I cant access Visual Studio now but trust me. You can set parameterized client side event handler wit OnClientClick - and this is really all you want.